# How do I find an index of a list member in R

Tags: r, list

assuming the simple code:

```
a <- list()
a[[1]] <- c(1,2,3)
a[[2]] <- c(2,3,4)
```

I want to ask about vector membership in the list and get the membership index.
So for asking about `c(1,2,3)` I will get `1`, and for asking about `c(2,3,4)` I will get 2. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

An option is to either use `setequal` or `all.equal` (from `base R`) by looping through the `list` elements, return a logical index and wrap with `which`

```
f1 <- function(lstObj, vec) {
 which(sapply(lstObj, setequal, vec))
 }

f1(a, 1:3)
#[1] 1

f1(a, 2:4)
#[1] 2
```

Also, as @IceCreamToucan mentioned in the comments

```
f1n <- function(lstObj, vec){
   which(sapply(lstObj, function(x, y) isTRUE(all.equal(x, y)), vec))
 }
```

---

Another option is `%in%` with `all`

```
f2 <- function(lstObj, vec) {
     which(sapply(lstObj, function(x) all(x %in% vec)))
  }
```

Comment: Good answer. Small note: If order matters, f1 function definition would need to be `which(sapply(lstObj, function(x, y) isTRUE(all.equal(x, y)), vec))`. An example for which the results differ: `f1(list(c(2, 1, 3)), 1:3)`

Comment: Isn't there a simpler solution? All this code just to ask if a vector is a member in the list?? Maybe a list is not the best way to go here in the sense of storing the vectors?

Comment: @Corel. If the `vector`s are of different lengths, a `list` would be appropriate.  If it is not, you can have it as a `matrix` or `data.frame`.  To check elements in a `list`, methods that can go inside the `list` would be useful.  Either `lapply/sapply/mapply` are used (in different context though).  Wrapping it inside a function is to make it simpler